# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_27a0_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)

Tags: magento-1.9

Can anyone help me to resolve this error on my magento website?

There has been an error processing your request

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file
>   '/tmp/#sql_27a0_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)

I have a dedicated server with Godaddy with 1TB of space.

My site is inaccessible.

Comment: It's quite obvious that space has run out on the partition where the mysql is storing data. You can free the storage on the partition or ask hosting guys to move your installation to a partition with more space. You can also ask hosting people to increase the size of partition where the mysql is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be connected with inodes. Maybe you have too many small files and your inodes are full. You can check inode status with df -i.

Or it can be connected with /tmp folder. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090073/mysql-incorrect-key-file-for-tmp-table-when-making-multiple-joins/3716778#3716778).

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing indicates that there is not enough space left on the device to create or write to a temporary file that is needed by MySQL.

1. This issue can be resolved by freeing up disk space on the device. Here are some steps you can take to free up disk space:
2. Identify the location of the device that is running out of space. You can do this by running the "df" command in the terminal.
3. Remove any unnecessary files or directories that are taking up space. You can use the "rm" command to delete files or the "rmdir" command to delete directories.
4. Clear the MySQL temporary directory. You can do this by running the command "sudo rm -rf /tmp/*" in the terminal.
5. Restart the MySQL service. You can do this by running the command "sudo service mysql restart" in the terminal.

If none of these steps resolve the issue, you may need to consider increasing the size of the device or moving the MySQL temporary directory to a different location with more available space.